# Swift extension for [String]?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write an extension method for `[String]`.

It seems you can't extend `[String]` directly ("Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'"), though I came across this trick:

```
protocol StringType { }
extension String: StringType { }
```

But I still can't quite make the Swift type system happy with this:

```
extension Array where Element: StringType {
    // ["a","b","c","d","e"] -> "a, b, c, d, or e".
    func joinWithCommas() -> String {
        switch count {
        case 0, 1, 2:
            return joinWithSeparator(" or ")
        default:
            return dropLast(1).joinWithSeparator(", ") + ", or " + last!
        }
    }
}
```

The `joinWithSeparator` calls are "Ambiguous".  I've tried everything I could think of, like using `(self as! [String])` (and a bunch of similar variants), but nothing seems to work.

How can I make the Swift compiler happy with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could follow the declaration of `joinWithSeparator` (Cmd-click on it) and find that it is defined as an extension of the protocol `SequenceType` instead of the type `Array`.

```
// swift 2:
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String {
    public func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String
}
```

(**Note:** In Xcode 8 / Swift 3 if you Cmd-click on `join(separator:)` you will land on `Array` even if it is [still implemented inside `Sequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e6f8843c701a0ea72ddfe0b5538b815767a4ee5d/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L567), but that won't invalidate the idea below)

We could do the same with your function, where we extend a protocol adopted by Array instead of Array itself:

```
// swift 2:
extension CollectionType where
        Generator.Element == String,
        SubSequence.Generator.Element == String,
        Index: BidirectionalIndexType
{
    func joinWithCommas() -> String {
        switch count {
        case 0, 1, 2:
            return joinWithSeparator(" or ")
        default:
            return dropLast(1).joinWithSeparator(", ") + ", or " + last!
        }
    }
}

// swift 3:
extension BidirectionalCollection where
        Iterator.Element == String,
        SubSequence.Iterator.Element == String
{
    func joinWithCommas() -> String {
        switch count {
        case 0, 1, 2:
            return joined(separator: " or ")
        default:
            return dropLast().joined(separator: ", ") + ", or " + last!
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

- we extend `CollectionType` to be able to use `count`
- we constraint `Generator.Element == String` to use `joinWithSeparator`
- we constraint `SubSequence.Generator.Element == String` to ensure `dropLast(1)` can use `joinWithSeparator`. `dropLast(1)` returns the associated type `SubSequence`.
- we constraint `Index: BidirectionalIndexType` to use `last`.

Comment: The verbosity. POP has it side-effects. Thanks for your solution ✌️

Answer (score 12):

edit/update

**Swift 4** or later it is better to constrain the collection elements to StringProtocol which will cover Substrings as well.

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element: StringProtocol {
    var joinedWithCommas: String {
        guard let last = last else { return "" }
        return count > 2 ? dropLast().joined(separator: ", ") + ", or " + last : joined(separator: " or ")
    }
}
```

---

And if all elements are just Characters we can simply extend StringProtocol:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func joined(with separator: String = ",", conector: String = "") -> String {
        guard let last = last else { return "" }
        if count > 2 {
            return dropLast().map(String.init).joined(separator: separator + " ") + separator + " " + conector + " " + String(last)
        }
        return map(String.init).joined(separator: " " + conector + " ")
    }
}
```

---

```
let elements = "abc"
let elementsJoined = elements.joined()                   // "a, b, c"
let elementsSeparated = elements.joined(conector: "or")  // "a, b, or c"
let elementsConected = elements.joined(conector: "and")  // "a, b, and c"
```

---

---

Original answer

In **Swift 3.1** (Xcode 8.3.2) you can simply extend Array constraining element type equal to String

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    var joinedWithCommas: String {
        guard let last = last else { return "" }
        return count > 2 ? dropLast().joined(separator: ", ") + ", or " + last : joined(separator: " or ")
    }
}
```

---

```
["a","b","c"].joinedWithCommas    // "a, b, or c"
```

Comment: We'll soon be saying .. "Remember the old days when we had to..."  :)