# With Data (not NSData), in fact how actually do you make a utf8 version of a jpeg?

Tags: swift, utf-8, httprequest

Exactly as explained here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30624755/294884

> [It is a mistake to think that] the JPEG representation of an image is a UTF-8-encoded string. **It's not.** It's arbitrary binary data. UTF-8 strings aren't arbitrary sequences of bytes; there are rules about what bytes can follow other bytes.

In fact, how *do* you best make a utf8 data from an image, in the `Data` era?

The everyday use case is in a http form.

I do something like this,

```
    formData.append( "Content-Disposition etc".(using: .utf8)! )
    formData.append( "Content type etc".(using: .utf8)! )

    // now let's add a #@@%$%$% image

    let trueBinary = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(i, 0.10)!
    print("the size seems to be \(trueBinary.count)")
    
    let mystere = trueBinary.base64EncodedString(
                  options: .lineLength76Characters)
    
    formData.append( mystere.data(using: .utf8)! )
```

But

## A, that seems poxy, and probably doesn't work anyway.

## B, the "lineLength" concept means nothing to me, so I just guess stuff, and type something in there.

Note that, incredibly confusingly, if you have a `Data` x and you add to x a few strings as utf8 using `append` ..... And then you add a 'real' binary data, such as a jpeg representation to `x` ...... **in fact it nils "x" - ouch!**  (It doesn't just "not add the binary one", it scratches x to nothing.)

Comment: As a curiosity, the latest version of AlamoFire seems to "make this mistake": if you use (as most people would) their convenience routine where you pass a file name, it seems to convert it the correct way.  But if you pass in an image, my initial investigations are that they "forget", as it were, to make it a utf8 data, and you get nothing.

Comment: Just convert your data to base64 string

Comment: but how, master Jedi?

Comment: What do you mean ? `data.base64EncodedString().utf8`

Comment: Or just `data.base64EncodedData()`

Comment: For any googlers: what Hamish's excellent tip means is, you can just **yourData.append( what Hamish said )**, rather than getting the image as a string S, and then **yourData.append( S converted to utf8 using what Leo said )**

Comment: @Hamish Do you know since when this was implemented ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/43811912/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus You mean concrete same-type requirements? (i.e `extension ConcreteType where X == Y {...}`). It was indeed introduced in Swift 3.1 (you can find it listed in [the Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)).

Comment: @Hamish Thanks I thought it was gonna be introduced in Swift 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has a problem:

```
let mystere = trueBinary.count.base64EncodedString(
              options: .lineLength76Characters)
```

The problem is that `trueBinary` is a `Data`, and `trueBinary.count` is an `Int`, and `Int` doesn't have a `base64EncodedString` method. You want this:

```
let mystere = trueBinary.base64EncodedString(
              options: .lineLength76Characters)
```

As for ‘the "lineLength" concept’: you don't have to specify a line length option if you don't want to. Arguably I shouldn't have specified one in the answer you referenced in your question, because [HTTP requests are not strictly MIME messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-A) and [are not subject to the MIME line length limit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-A.6). You can do this instead:

```
let mystere = trueBinary.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: Thanks, @LeoDabus. I have modified my answer.

Comment: thanks Rob - (Damn, the .count was a typo; hope it doesn't confuse any googlers.)

Comment: the two MIME links are ***epic info***, thanks @robmayoff